# Problem with java app and hosted DBs

Tags: java, database, postgresql, hosting

Some time ago, I started a new Java app wich function was to provide access to a remote DB, to browse, sort, filter and operate with some registers. To test it out, I was using a PostgreSQL DB located in my PC and then I finished the Java app. Everything was fine so I was about to rent a hosting service only for my DB, to provide real service. The thing is that I haven't found any hosting company who provides direct DB access through JDBC f.e. For security reasons they don't permit that.

Does anyone know a hosting service wich allows PostgreSQL + direct DB access? 
If not, the other way to do it is to create a WS in php f.e., to connect to the DB and then make my Java app to use that WS. But thats A LOT of extra work (I have many procedures) and I have little time.

Thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can always get a VPS solution where you are open to install whatever you want and however you want to use the services. Usually you will not find PostgreSQL service providers (or any other database for that matter) which exposes its ports on the internet, usually databases are meant to be access by App servers. For my company's PostgreSQL hosting, we use AWS instances with Resin Caucho as Java app server.

Answer (score 0):

you can always stand up an AWS instance with the servlet container and database of your choice.  i wouldn't be surprised if they had pre-defined instances with the appropriate configuration (maybe something like tomcat and mysql).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to find hosting which provides dedicated server? It's more expensive than usually but you can do on computer (or VM) everything that you want. It shoud solve your problem.

UPD.

I also can suggest this pretty nice startup http://jelastic.com/